# Is it possible to do arithmetic operation on OuterRef expression?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I'm building an Experience booking system in django and I've the following models.

```
class Experience(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
 capacity = models.IntegerField()

class Booking(models.Model):
 experience = models.ForeignKey(Experience)
 occupied = models.IntegerField()
```

Each experience has a limited number of capacity and when user perform booking, it will be added to the Booking table with occupied number. Now how will I find the experiences which are not occupied completely?

```
available_experiences = Experience.objects.all().exclude(id__in=Subquery(Booking.objects.filter(occupied__gt=OuterRef('capacity') - request_persons).values_list('experience', flat=True)))
```

Here, `request_persons` is the number of required vacancy in an experience. This is not working and showing an error like `'ResolvedOuterRef' object has no attribute 'relabeled_clone'`. Is it possible to do arithmetic operation on `OutRef()` expression like `F()`?

Without adding `request_persons`, the above code works. Why it is not possible to add a value to the `OutRef()` expression?

NOTE: My actual code is much complex one and it will be really great to get an answer without modifying the entire structure of the above code.

Comment: For what it is worth, I created a ticket for this in the Django IssueTracker: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29142

Comment: Yes, this was indeed a bug... ;)

Answer (score 1):

By doing arithmetic operations in the query referenced by `OuterRef()` directly you can resolve this issue:

```
available_experiences = Experience.objects.annotate(
    total=models.F('capacity') - request_persons
).exclude(
    id__in=Subquery(Booking.objects.filter(
        occupied__gt=OuterRef('total')
    ).values_list('experience', flat=True))
)
```

If you found another way without modifying your structure or using `RawSQL()` or `.extra()`, let us know!

Comment: This is exactly what I did as of now. Looks like it is not possible to perform arithmetic operation on OuterRef expression.

Comment: There are cases where this does not help though, resulting in a `GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING` error. Depending on what `request_persons` might be, Django 2.0.1 incorrectly subsitutes the `OuterRef()` with `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed in Django 2.0: https://github.com/django/django/pull/9722/files

The fix can be backported to 1.11.x in a similar fashion:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import ResolvedOuterRef
if not hasattr(ResolvedOuterRef, 'relabeled_clone'):
    ResolvedOuterRef.relabeled_clone = lambda self, relabels: self
```